# This driver is not configured for integrated authentication, any ideas

Tags: java, sql-server, intellij-idea, database-connection

I keep getting this error while I try to connect to SQL server with integrated security, can anyone help please.

> > This driver is not configured for integrated authentication

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    
    try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.0.52;database = AMFN_Creator;integratedSecurity=true;");
    }
}
```

Comment: what version of the sql jdbc driver are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JDBC SQLServerException: "This driver is not configured for integrated authentication."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087819/jdbc-sqlserverexception-this-driver-is-not-configured-for-integrated-authentic)

Comment: I am using version jdbc 8.2.1 jre13