# Connect to SQL Server using Hibernate

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, maven, jdbc

I'm trying to connect to SQL Server with Java using a Maven project and Hibernate.

First of all, I created maven project using IntelliJ IDEA IDE, this is how my pom.xml looks like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>SimpleChat</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>15</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>15</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>9.2.0.jre15</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.28.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.30</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.30</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

So here I have placed dependencies of the SQL Server JDBC driver, Hibernate libraries and some of Java assist service libraries.

Next I created hibernate.cfg.xml file to configure my connection settings:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;database=SimpleChat;integratedSecurity=true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">sa</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">1234</property>

        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

This is how my project hierarchy looks like:

```
project:
|----src/main
|
|--------|java
|        |
|--------|----|ge.server.chat
|        |    |
|--------|----|----|db
|        |    |    |  
|--------|----|----|----|model
|        |    |    |    |
|--------|----|----|----|----User.java
|        |    |    |
|--------|----|----|----JdbcConnection.java
|        |    |
|--------|----|----|main
|        |    |    |
|--------|----|----|----App.java
|
|--------|resources
|        |
|--------|----hibernate.cfg.xml

----pom.xml
```

Here are shown how my Java classes looks like.

User.java:

```java
package ge.server.chat.db.model;

import com.sun.istack.NotNull;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "username", unique = true)
    @NotNull
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password")
    @NotNull
    private String password;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [id=" + id + ", username=" + username + ", password=" + password + "]";
    }

}
```

JdbcConnection.java:

```java
package ge.server.chat.db;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;

public class JdbcConnection {
    private Session session;
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private volatile static SessionFactory INSTANCE = null;

    private JdbcConnection() {}

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            createSessionFactory();
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    private synchronized static void createSessionFactory() {
        if (INSTANCE != null) {
            return;
        }

        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
        configuration.addAnnotatedClass(ge.server.chat.db.model.User.class);

        try {
            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                    .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
            INSTANCE = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

App.java:

```java
package ge.server.chat.main;

import ge.server.chat.db.JdbcConnection;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello Hibernate!!!");
        Session session = JdbcConnection.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

        transaction.commit();
        session.close();
    }
}
```

The database named SimpleChat does not yet have any table. After running this app, it should create empty table named Users, that should do transaction. But when I try to run the project it ends with driver manager initialization error. Here is full stack trace:

```java
მარ 09, 2021 1:30:17 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.28.Final
მარ 09, 2021 1:30:17 AM org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.stax.LocalXmlResourceResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH90000012: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration instead.  Support for obsolete DTD/XSD namespaces may be removed at any time.
მარ 09, 2021 1:30:18 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
მარ 09, 2021 1:30:19 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
მარ 09, 2021 1:30:19 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver] at URL [jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;database=SimpleChat;integratedSecurity=true]
მარ 09, 2021 1:30:19 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {password=****, user=sa}
მარ 09, 2021 1:30:19 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
მარ 09, 2021 1:30:19 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
მარ 09, 2021 1:30:34 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator initiateService
WARN: HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a connection as the driver manager is not properly initialized
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:172)
    at ge.server.chat.main.App.main(App.java:10)

მარ 09, 2021 1:30:34 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
მარ 09, 2021 1:30:34 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08S01
მარ 09, 2021 1:30:34 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: This driver is not configured for integrated authentication. ClientConnectionId:cd5b065a-6eee-411b-ae76-15830d84f5cb
org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:275)
    at ge.server.chat.main.App.main(App.java:10)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:41)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.addConnections(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:341)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.<init>(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:260)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.<init>(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:238)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections$Builder.build(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:379)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: This driver is not configured for integrated authentication. ClientConnectionId:cd5b065a-6eee-411b-ae76-15830d84f5cb
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:3208)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.AuthenticationJNI.<init>(AuthenticationJNI.java:72)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:4017)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:4006)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7418)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:3274)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:2768)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:2418)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:2265)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1291)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:881)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:38)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no mssql-jdbc_auth-9.2.0.x64 in java.library.path: C:\OpenJDK-15\java-15-openjdk\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\OpenJDK-15\java-15-openjdk\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2017a\runtime\win64;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2017a\bin;C:\msys64\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_271\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Azure Data Studio\bin;C:\apache\Apache24\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\OpenJDK-15\java-15-openjdk\bin;C:\Users\ltsir\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\ltsir\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\Azure Data Studio\bin;C:\sqljdbc_8.4.1.0_enu\sqljdbc_8.4\enu\auth\x64;C:\Gradle\gradle-6.8\bin;C:\Users\ltsir\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\maven\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin;;.
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2447)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:809)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1893)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.AuthenticationJNI.<clinit>(AuthenticationJNI.java:51)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:4016)
    ... 39 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.SessionFactory.openSession()" because the return value of "ge.server.chat.db.JdbcConnection.getSessionFactory()" is null
    at ge.server.chat.main.App.main(App.java:10)
```

I could not find any related topic or question or solution to this kind of error, so any help would be much appreciated.

I tried:

- In separate project using this driver class name, connection URL, username, password and SimpleChat database to connect manually to the DB using low-level JDBC connection and driver manager directly. Fortunately it succeed and that, I hope, means that this strings are correct and are usable.
- To build project manually, using mvn clean install command from cmd, to see if there was problem, or not, with maven itself, but again, the build was success and no problems were found.

Comment: error message clearly says  "no mssql-jdbc_auth-9.2.0.x64 in java.library.path"

Comment: You could check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087819/jdbc-sqlserverexception-this-driver-is-not-configured-for-integrated-authentic