# SQLServerException: This driver is not configured for integrated authentication. ClientConnectionId:ac8ee3bc-e4b0-4cb9-9dcd-f83ce3eab689

Tags: java, sql-server, jsp, jdbc, mssql-jdbc

I was trying to run a simple JSP file to retrieve data from Microsoft SQL Server using following simple code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import= "java.sql.* "%>    
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
out.println("Comand completed successfully"+"<br>");
String connString="jdbc:sqlserver://DESKTOP-HTN7DNE\\MSSQLSERVER;"+"databaseName=Hospital_Mmg_System; integratedSecurity=true;";
Connection conn= DriverManager.getConnection(connString);
Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
String query="Select * From patient";
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(query);

while(rs.next()) {
    out.println(rs.getString(1)+"  "+rs.getString(2)+"  "+rs.getString(3)+"  "+ rs.getString(4)+"  "+ rs.getString(5)+"  "+ rs.getString(6)+"<br>");
}
%>
```

I faced that error, then I copied the `mssql-jdbc_auth-9.2.1.x64.dll` file and pasted in the Java `bin` folder and it worked.

But then I'm trying to run another JSP file to insert data to the database using the following simple codes:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*,java.util.*"%>

<%
String first_name=request.getParameter("first_name");
String last_name=request.getParameter("last_name");
String city_name=request.getParameter("city_name");
String email=request.getParameter("email");


Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
String connString="jdbc:sqlserver://DESKTOP-HTN7DNE\\MSSQLSERVER;"+"databaseName=Test; integratedSecurity=true;";
Connection conn= DriverManager.getConnection(connString);
Statement st=conn.createStatement();

int i=st.executeUpdate("insert into users(first_name,last_name,city_name,email)values('"+first_name+"','"+last_name+"','"+city_name+"','"+email+"')");
out.println("Data is successfully inserted!");
%>
```

I'm faced with the same error. I have already pasted this `mssql-jdbc_auth-9.2.1.x64.dll` in the Java `bin` file, then why this error again? What should I do now?

Comment: Will this Stack Overflow Answer Help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/6087911/15590269

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087819/jdbc-sqlserverexception-this-driver-is-not-configured-for-integrated-authentic