# Java Spring-Boot REST API Fails to When Pointing to Local SQL Server Instance

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, rest

So my rest API is failing to run against my configured SQL Server DB. I'm going to list everything I have tried and confirmed down below the pasted code. I feel like it's something silly that is stopping it from running, but I can't figure it out.

Error Message:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: This driver is not configured for integrated authentication. ClientConnectionId:a20200ea-d191-4404-8445-05ea0a3c2af8
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:3806) ~[mssql-jdbc-11.2.3.jre17.jar:na]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.AuthenticationJNI.<init>(AuthenticationJNI.java:74) ~[mssql-jdbc-11.2.3.jre17.jar:na]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:4860) ~[mssql-jdbc-11.2.3.jre17.jar:na]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:4849) ~[mssql-jdbc-11.2.3.jre17.jar:na]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7620) ~[mssql-jdbc-11.2.3.jre17.jar:na]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:3916) ~[mssql-jdbc-11.2.3.jre17.jar:na]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:3358) ~[mssql-jdbc-11.2.3.jre17.jar:na]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:2950) ~[mssql-jdbc-11.2.3.jre17.jar:na]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:2790) ~[mssql-jdbc-11.2.3.jre17.jar:na]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1663) ~[mssql-jdbc-11.2.3.jre17.jar:na]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1064) ~[mssql-jdbc-11.2.3.jre17.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:121) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:358) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:477) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:560) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:158) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:116) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:79) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:324) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.isEmbedded(EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.java:120) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateDefaultDdlAutoProvider.getDefaultDdlAuto(HibernateDefaultDdlAutoProvider.java:42) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration.lambda$getVendorProperties$1(HibernateJpaConfiguration.java:130) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateSettings.getDdlAuto(HibernateSettings.java:41) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties.determineDdlAuto(HibernateProperties.java:136) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]    
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties.getAdditionalProperties(HibernateProperties.java:102) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties.determineHibernateProperties(HibernateProperties.java:94) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration.getVendorProperties(HibernateJpaConfiguration.java:132) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.entityManagerFactory(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:133) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:650) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:635) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1176) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]        
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1109) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
        at com.example.myproject.Main.main(Main.java:11) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load authentication DLL mssql-jdbc_auth-11.2.3.x64
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.AuthenticationJNI.<clinit>(AuthenticationJNI.java:63) ~[mssql-jdbc-11.2.3.jre17.jar:na]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:4859) ~[mssql-jdbc-11.2.3.jre17.jar:na]
        ... 54 common frames omitted
```

`src/main/resources/application.properties` is designed as:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=TestDB;integratedSecurity=true;trustServerCertificate=true;
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

`pom.xml`

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example.myproject</groupId>
  <artifactId>Java_API</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency> 


    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
      <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>11.2.3.jre17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

  
  </dependencies>

  <properties>
     <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
     <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>3.0.2</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

- Checked the connection properties to ensure that they are correct. I think I have done this, but I am using localhost as my SQL server instance name, so maybe this is the problem?
- Made sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port
- Checked TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.
- Checked that an instance of SQL Server is running and accepting connections.
- Java -version:17  jdbc installed version: `11.2.3.jre17`
- I have tried using the datasource `user:<server Name>` with no `password:` in the datasource url because my SQL Server is set to Windows Authentication so there is a username, but no password.
- I have tried to use `user:root` `password:password` in the datasource URL which is what was configured when I installed SQL server.I had to create a password and I just left the user root.

Comment: check if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087819/jdbc-sqlserverexception-this-driver-is-not-configured-for-integrated-authentic) helps

Comment: hi @user21086690 no problem , if you were able to resolve the issue that is well and good . possibly a duplicate query . you can try searching first and start creating a query !!

Answer (score 2):

@thar45 pointed me to the answer of this question for me so I would like to thank him in full.

After copying the dll to the java bin (read solution provided from @thar45)

I then also had to add the following dependencies to my pom.xml:

```
<!-- API -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Runtime -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

After this I was able to run against run my rest API with configured datasource.